# Servicing a WIM image with the recently released SP1 for Windows 7/Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, wds, wim

I normally hang out over on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/) but wanted to ask this question in a more appropriate forum. I have, for the sheer fun of learning how to do (as I'm sick of GHOST and dd images) set up WDS and captured a reference WIM file.

One of the things that I remember being promised was the ability to do offline servicing of WIM files. I'm just wondering what the actual procedure is for this?

I have the full SP1 ISO down (covers 7 and 2008R2) and was wondering about next steps. If someone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it greatly.

Thanks
- Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you have WAIK installed,  you can service wim files by using DISM to mount and add files to wim, add drivers, remove drivers, etc.

These links should help you out:

[General Overview of using DISM for drivers, feaures, packages,unattend](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744382%28WS.10%29.aspx)

[WAIK for Windows 7 SP1](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mniehaus/archive/2011/02/17/windows-aik-for-windows-7-sp1-released.aspx) If you're interested in latest and greatest.

Comment: Thanks very much! The WAIK for Windows 7 SP1 link looks particularly interesting...